# Using WK ID's when using CreateSpatialReference tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy

I recently found out how to create specific spatial reference objects and add them to my arcgis python standalone script. `sp=arcpy.CreateSpatialReference_management("GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],VERTCS['NAVD_1988',VDATUM['North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988'],PARAMETER['Vertical_Shift',0.0],PARAMETER['Direction',1.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];-400 -400 1000000000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98315284119521E-09;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision","#","#","#","#","#","0")`

As you can see, this is painfully long and is subject to errors. I would like to know how to go about shortening the input required to make this tool functional. Where can I place well-known ESRI ID's to simplify the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
my_sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(my_wkid)
```

Then use `my_sr` however you wish.

[ESRI Documentation - ArcPy SpatialReference](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z0000000v000000)

Comment: Problem is, i got to define Projected Coordinate System for my Horizontal and Vertical Coordinate System for my elevations. Maybe VERTCS[wkid] would work?? thoughts? I cannot build my feature dataset without clearly defining both.

Comment: Didn't notice the need for a VCS. Maybe use the arcpy.SpatialReference('c:/my_fc.prj') method. Create a prj file and load that into the SpatialReference class. I tested it and it appears to work fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little further? I am more of a programmer than GIS proficient. Why wouldn't there be the need for a VCS?

Comment: VCS allows for GIS recognition of the z-dimension. (Judging from the similar question you previously asked, you'll need it set for elevation purposes.)

Comment: Oh ok, how would the projection file have both horizontal and vertical references?

Comment: The projection file is really just a flat text file that would contain the your string `GEOGCS...->IsHighPrecision`. In hindsight, it wouldn't really improve the process much if your goal is to manipulate everything in code.

Comment: My main issue is recurrent changes to my spatial reference. As I get new data, my coordinate system will change depending on what it reads of the incoming text files. I wanted to completely automate that without the need for my colleagues to manually change it on ArcGIS

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to create the 'flat' CRS by EPSG/SRID code then use the .setZFalseOriginAndUnits (false_z, z_units) method of the returned spatial reference to set the Z parameters (if needed) You should only need to set the Z portion if you're *actually* using it and if it's different to the default somehow... How do you receive your input data @user40720?

Comment: I receive my data in a .xyz formated text file.